# Fish function option/param parser

Tags: parsing, fish

It seems that there is some work in progress to add support for this in the future:

https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/478
https://github.com/xiaq/fish-shell/tree/opt-parse

But in the meantime, what's the recommended way to deal with this? Should I just parse $argv? If so do you have some tips/best practices?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm note sure if it is a best practice, but in the meantime you could do something like this:

```
function options
  echo $argv | sed 's|--*|\\'\n'|g' | grep -v '^$'
end

function function_with_options
  for i in (options $argv)
    echo $i | read -l option value

    switch $option
      case a all
        echo all the things
      case f force
        echo force it
      case i ignore
        echo ignore the $value
    end
  end
end
```

Output:

```
➤ function_with_options -i thing -a --force
ignore the thing
all the things
force it
```

Comment: Is this still state of the art for fish?

Comment: Yes, there is nothing in `fish` to deal with this yet. You could of course also use `getopt` like some internal functions in fish does. But then you have to deal with different versions of `getopt` etc. See the fish functions `psub`, `umask` and `trap` for getopt examples.

Answer (score 15):

Parsing `$argv` is fine for basic scenarios but can otherwise become tedious and error prone.

Before fish had its own argument parsing solution, the community created:

- [getopts.fish](https://github.com/jorgebucaran/getopts)

**As of fish 2.7.0, you can use fish's built-in option parser: [argparse](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/commands.html#argparse)**

```
function foo --description "Example argparse usage"
  set --local options 'h/help' 'n/count=!_validate_int --min 1'

  argparse $options -- $argv

  if set --query _flag_help
    printf "Usage: foo [OPTIONS]\n\n"
    printf "Options:\n"
    printf "  -h/--help       Prints help and exits\n"
    printf "  -n/--count=NUM  Count (minimum 1, default 10)"
    return 0
  end

  set --query _flag_count; or set --local _flag_count 10

  for i in (seq $_flag_count); echo foo; end
end
```

To see the full extent of what's possible, run `argparse -h` or `argparse --help`.

Comment: Thank you for your response... It has been really useful for me.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this:

```
for item in $argv
    switch "$item"
        case -f --foo
        case -b --bar
    end
end
```

The above does not support writing short options in a single argument `-fbz`, option values `--foo=baz`, `--foo baz` or `f baz`, negative assignment `--name!=value`, end of options `--` and dashes `-` and `--` are always part of the argument.

To address these issues, I wrote a [getopts](https://github.com/bucaran/fish-getopts) function.

```
getopts -ab1 --foo=bar baz
```

Now look at the output.

```
a
b    1
foo  bar
_    baz
```

The items on the *left* represent the option flags or *keys* associated with the CLI. The items on the *right* are the option *values*. The underscore `_` character is the default *key* for arguments without a key.

Use [`read(1)`](http://fishshell.com/docs/current/commands.html#read) to process the generated stream and [`switch(1)`](http://fishshell.com/docs/current/commands.html#switch) to match patterns:

```
getopts -ab1 --foo=bar baz | while read -l key option
    switch $key
        case _
        case a
        case b
        case foo
    end
end
```

See the [documentation](https://github.com/fisherman/getopts#getopts).